# Express.JS functions inside session being cleared

Tags: node.js, function, express, object, oop

I would like to put a User class inside my session so I would be able to use it anywhere.

But the problem is that I currently cannot do that, when I put custom types inside my session such as Functions, it seems to just remove them, which is a need for what I am coding right now.

Here is a demonstration

```js
async function newRequest(req, res)
{
    if (!req.session.user) 
        req.session.user = new User.Instance(sql);

    console.log(typeof await req.session.user.loginsValid)

    if (req.session.user.authentified && await req.session.user.loginsValid())
        router = new Router("Connected"); 
    else 
        router = new Router("Disconnected");


    router.Start(req, res, sql);
}
```

here is the output after loading 2 times the page

> root@networkConf:/home# node app.js
> function
> undefined

Comment: Sessions will be serialized as text when stored so you can generally only put strings and numbers in sessions. Functions generally cannot be serialized into a string unless you provide your own serializer/de-serializer

Comment: I see, yeah then i would have to remove the serialization